# Execute Effect.Move more than once in prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, effects, marquee

I am trying to recreate the behaviour of HTML marquee tag, but I am dealing with this issue, Effect.Move is firing only once, no matters the recursion applied.

```
function MoveNoticias() {
new Effect.Move('moverlo', { x: -10, y: 0, mode: 'relative' });
    setTimeout("MoveNoticias", 10);
}
```

Any ideas why? I have to say that I do not like prototype at all, I use to work with Jquery, but in this case, unfortunately, I need to use prototype.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `setTimeout(MoveNoticias, 10);`. Your `setTimeout` is not actually doing anything at the moment.

Comment: Now it is working. But, do you know some way to make it circular?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an inifinit loop by using the **afterFinish**-Event, like this:

```
function MoveNoticias(){
    new Effect.Move('moverlo', {
        x:-10, y:0, mode:'relative',
        afterFinish:MoveNoticias});
}
```

I set up a [working example for you](http://jsfiddle.net/Jn8D8/).
Your next question probably will be, how to 'marquee' the whole thing back; well you should dynamically calculate x by measuring how far the marquee already moved and eventually switch the direction.